# This does not work in IE ... Can anyone lend their brain as to why?

Tags: jquery

I have this small piece of code that simply pulls in a news release from one of our sites:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        items = [];
        curr_item = 0;
        $.getJSON('/press-release/feed/', function(data){
            items = data;
            render(0);
            next = setInterval(next_release, 5000);
    });

    function next_release() {
        //make sure we can't fall off the end of the array
        if(curr_item == items.length-1)
            curr_item = 0;
        else
            curr_item++;

        render(curr_item);
    }

    function render( index ) {
        item = items[index].fields;
        $('#ticker-text a').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(this).attr('href', '/press-release/' + item.slug).text(item.title);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
     }

    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="news-ticker">
        <span id="ticker-text"><a href=""></a></span>
         <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

For some reason this does not render the press release text from the JSON string in IE but it works fine in safari, chrome, firefox, opera... Can anyone help?

Comment: and are you getting javascript errors? or just no return?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what is or is not happening?  Also, just use the debugger in IE8 or IE9 and put in breakpoints, see where it doesn't get to, and that will help track down the problem.  On my computer hitting F12 brings up the debugger.

Comment: The error I am getting is: Webpage error details

Message: Object doesn't support this action
Line: 28
Char: 8
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.1.101:8000/media/press_release/js/ticker.js
which is "item = items[index].fields;" Thanks, I should have noted that in my questions as well.

Comment: are you sure that "data" has a value in the getJson callback?  Have you looked at that in the debugger?  The error would indicate that fields isn't present in the object.

Comment: David, yes, data gives me back [object Object]

Comment: Try outputting data.toSource(); if this helps

Comment: Do you have `var items;` anywhere (also `var curr_item;` and `var next;`)?  Maybe IE doesn't like implied globals?

Comment: data.toSource gives me the json string in firefox and every other browser, IE gives me an error: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 13
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.1.101:8000/media/press_release/js/ticker.js and now my line 13 in this source code is: alert(data.toSource());

Comment: Oh well that's interesting I did add "var" infront of those as per Johns suggestion and I do seethe text now show up just like in firefox but the "next_release" method does not seem to be working in ie... getting closer!

Comment: Ah I got it! thanks a lot guys, I guess IE forces you to declare your vars first? best practice? (though, I don't think IE and best practice should ever be in the same context)

Comment: IE really does a good job of enforcing correctness in JS.  It will fail on {'aaa','bbb',} due to the trailing comma, where FF and Chrome will ignore the error.  It's sometimes maddening to find the problem, but once you do your code is better for it.

Comment: JeffC - Since this is resolved, you should answer the question with what worked, and then accept it. That way it doesn't show up as unanswered!

Comment: Michal, Sorry, how do I make this as resolved, i don't see that anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"IE really does a good job of enforcing correctness in JS. It will fail on `{'aaa','bbb',}` due to the trailing comma, where `FF` and Chrome will ignore the error. It's sometimes maddening to find the problem, but once you do your code is better for it."

-- Thanks David this was the issue.